# How to use proxies for different services/programs in php script

Tags: php, linux, proxy, centos

I have this test php script:

```
<?php

$proxy = "62.111.14.138:80";
$proxy2 = "104.111.208.238:80";

$_SERVER["http_proxy"] = "http://name:pass@".$proxy;
$_SERVER["https_proxy"] = "http://name:pass@".$proxy;

print_r($_SERVER["http_proxy"]);
echo "\n";
print_r($_SERVER["https_proxy"]);
echo "\n";

$string = ('./speedtest-cli');
  $descriptorspec = array(
      0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
      1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
      2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
      );
  $process = proc_open($string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
  $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);
  $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
  fclose($pipes[2]);
  $ret = proc_close($process);
  echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret, 'errors' => $stderr,
  'output' => $stdout,
  'command' => $string));
echo "\n";

$_SERVER["http_proxy"] = "http://name:pass@".$proxy2;
$_SERVER["https_proxy"] = "http://name:pass@".$proxy2;

print_r($_SERVER["http_proxy"]);
echo "\n";
print_r($_SERVER["https_proxy"]);
echo "\n";

$string = ('./speedtest-cli');
  $descriptorspec = array(
      0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
      1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
      2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
      );
  $process = proc_open($string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
  $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);
  $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
  fclose($pipes[2]);
  $ret = proc_close($process);
  echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret, 'errors' => $stderr,
  'output' => $stdout,
  'command' => $string));
  echo "\n";

?>
```

The output:

```
http://name:pass@62.111.14.138:80
http://name:pass@62.111.14.138:80
{"status":0,"errors":"","output":"Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...\nRetrieving speedtest.net server list...\nTesting from OVH SAS (92.111.195.34)...\nSelecting best server based on latency...\nHosted by FreeMobile (Paris) [1.30 km]: 8.026 ms\nTesting download speed........................................\nDownload: 204.45 Mbit\/s\nTesting upload speed..................................................\nUpload: 18.70 Mbit\/s\n","command":".\/speedtest-cli"}
http://name:pass@104.111.208.238:80
http://name:pass@104.111.208.238:80
{"status":0,"errors":"","output":"Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...\nRetrieving speedtest.net server list...\nTesting from OVH SAS (92.111.195.34)...\nSelecting best server based on latency...\nHosted by FreeMobile (Paris) [1.30 km]: 8.494 ms\nTesting download speed........................................\nDownload: 162.78 Mbit\/s\nTesting upload speed..................................................\nUpload: 18.94 Mbit\/s\n","command":".\/speedtest-cli"}
```

Looks like it ignores proxies and just use server's ip `92.111.195.34`

How can I make it to use the specified proxies instead of server's ip?

I'm using:

CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2014 12:59:36)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to [Arnau Sanchez aka tokland](https://github.com/tokland)

Here is the solution

```
http_proxy=xyz https_proxy=xyz ./speedtest-cli
```

So we can use it like:

```
$http_proxy = "http://name:pass@1.1.1.1:80";
$https_proxy = "http://name:pass@1.1.1.1:80";

$string = ('http_proxy='.$http_proxy.' https_proxy='.$https_proxy.' ./speedtest-cli');
  $descriptorspec = array(
      0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
      1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
      2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
      );
  $process = proc_open($string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
  $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);
  $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
  fclose($pipes[2]);
  $ret = proc_close($process);
  echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret, 'errors' => $stderr,
  'output' => $stdout,
  'command' => $string));
```

Comment: @Eborbob Thank you for reminding me this. I wasn't able to do it after I post it, cuz it was my own answer on my own question - so I had to wait couple days to be able to accept it :) Again, thank you.